# Access Database

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need help in creating an query interface with access database.
In brief, with this query interface I want to see calculated future dates for different steps of a process based on the date the process actually started.
The future dates will always be at a fixed number of days after the start date. I hope I am able to explain this in an understandable manner.

I was thinking of using access forms? Please help me in this. I am not sure of how to proceed with this.

Comment: Where do yo want to run this? That is, who are your users, and where will they be using this interface? And what will the output format be? Display only? Export to CSV or Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is already in MS Access, then using Access Forms would be your easiest method of displaying that data. If the data is elsewhere, such as in Sql Server, you may be better suited in the long run using a different display technology.

That being said, to select a number of dates, as you would do in Access, you can use the [Date Add function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/add-to-or-subtract-from-date-and-time-values-HP001098485.aspx). If you had a table Processes with a column StartDate, you could use the query

```
SELECT *, DateAdd("d",5,StartDate) as "5 Days", DateAdd("d",36,StartDate) as "36 Days"
FROM Processes
```

to generate a record set to bind your form to. Binding that query to a new form is easy. You just need to [change the record source](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/change-the-record-source-or-connection-information-HP005187656.aspx) by:

1. Right click anywhere blank in your new form
2. Select Properties
3. Change to the data tab
4. Click the button next to the text box labeled "Record Source"
5. Build your query using the built in editor (or, to paste the given SQL, right click in the designer view and select SQL view, then paste)
6. Close the query building dialog and use your new fields. You can drag them from the field list onto the design surface.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was able to create a form that would give me a list of future dates (yaaayyyy!! :)). But I want to create an end user interface (GUI), a kind of desktop application which can be accessed from any PC. Is that possible by usign Access forms?

Comment: Also I was thinking of attaching a dummy interface I created to give you a better idea. Is is possible to attach that dummy here?

Comment: Why would where the data is stored determine the front end? Isn't where the data needs to be USED/VIEWED the determininant, instead? That is, Access can display SQL Server data just fine, but if it needs to be accessible via the web browser, you wouldn't want to spend your time building an Access form.

Comment: Thanks david. Its an desktop application and does not necessarily have to be web application. In general if I want to create an query end user interface, how can I do that with either access or SQL database?